Arabic font in chromium suddenly changed?
I use chromium browser from snap store It's set to English but then when I visit a website with Arabic text it used to show in the same font that is in the tab and the window bar, I really don't like this font it's difficult to read and ugly how do I set the default font for Arabic in chromium ?
before

after

EDIT !
I tried setting the default font through chromium appearance settings, It seems to work sometimes but mostly not, as you can see the fonts in the picture are not the same.

